# Python - как обратиться к классу в классе

Tags: python, классы, peewee

Нужно получить table_name, но при `ClassName.Meta.table_name` возникает ошибка.

```
class ClassName(BaseModel):
    rows = ..
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'abv'
```

Как правильно это сделать?
Это peewee.

Comment: надо создать экземпляр класса внтури класса. А вы его не создали.

Comment: а, поняла вас, спасибо. Это автогенерируемые классы peewee, не очень хочется их менять. Получается тогда никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте работать через `_meta`:

```
print(ClassName._meta.table_name)
# abv
```